# Generate JSON data from the JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm looking for a Java library or a script which generates JSON data based upon the input schema that I provide.

For e.g. 
Json Schema:

```
{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

**Json data file**

```
{
"firstname":"abc"
"lastName":"def"
"age":"25"
}
```

**JSON data file 2:**

```
{
"firstname":"xxx"
"lastName":"777"
"age":"3#"
}
```

I can provide the JSON values both valid and invalid values in a file to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

To generate data programmatically these can be helpful.

http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

If you want to generate random JSON then you can try:-

1. https://generatedata.com/generator
2. https://www.json-generator.com/
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#generate-random-data

Comment: http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com. This link doesnt produce any code.And this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org i will look in to it

Comment: no !!! my friend both link are working. add your external link containing json example as shown like this in the form >> http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/booklist.json

Comment: Both of these generate Java code.  OP asked for randomized JSON data.  This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @gregsdennis Please check the update. It may be helpful